How to change shading detail?
I want to do something about triangle vertex shading and give vertices of a triangle red, green and blue like this.
The color of the triangle face is decided automatically by smooth shading. Is there any way I can find the specific shading function or theory and change it? For example, I want some colors to have more or less impact on coloring the face. How can I achieve it? Is shading nodes can do such things?

I might try subdividing the size of the triangle after the vertex coloring was applied, and then sliding those middle vertices on the outer edges, so they’d basically function as half point stops for the gradients? IDK if that would work.

@TheLabCat It works, thanks for inspiration

The interpolation of an attribute such as smoothed normal across a shaded triangle from its face-corners is linearly weighted by the barycentric coordinates of the shading-point.
If you want some other function of barycentric UVW on faces of a triangulated surface, Geometry > Parametric would the way to your raw material:

For example:


It's useful, I will go deep about this and figure what can I get. Thank!
